# How to test namespaced mapAction in Vue

Tags: vue.js, testing, vuex

I have a namespaced Vuex store in my Vue 2.6 app one module of which is like this:

```
 //books.js

 export default {
  state: {
    books: null
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_BOOKS(state, books) {
      state.books = books;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setBooks: async function ({ commit }) {
      //api call
      commit('SET_BOOKS', books);
    }
  },
  namespaced: true
};
```

I want to test a component that calls the `setBooks` action. I am using `mapActions` to access the actions. The relevant code is:

```
 //Books.vue

 methods: {
    ...mapActions("books", ["setBooks"]),
    }
  },
  created: async function() {
    await this.setBooks();
  }
```

The problem is that my test can't find the action:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Books from '@/views/Books';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises';
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

describe('Books', () => {

  let actions;
  let store;
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        books: {
          books: null
        }
      },
      actions: {
        setBooks: jest.fn()
      }
    });
    wrapper = shallowMount(Books, { store, localVue })
  });

  it("renders the books", async () => {
    await flushPromises();
    expect(actions.setBooks).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I get an error `[vuex] module namespace not found in mapActions(): books/`

if I try to namespace the actions code in the my test to:

```
actions: {
    books: {
        setBooks: jest.fn()
    }
}
```

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBooks' of undefined`

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for vue-test-utils include [an example of testing with modules](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html#mocking-with-modules).

Change your beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  actions = { setBooks: jest.fn() }
  store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      books: {
        state: { books: null },
        actions
      }
    }
  })
...
})
```

Your test calls actions.setBooks, but in your original code actions was simply declared, but not used in the creation of your store.

Comment: thanks, I was importing that from another file but I changed the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Create the actions object before your create the mock store.  Your original code declared an actions object with the let keyword, but it remains undefined.

Comment: I still get the `[vuex] module namespace not found in mapActions(): setting/` which makes sense since nowhere does the actions object specifiy the namespace....thanks for your help though....one related question is in the test if I do `expect(actions.books.setBooks).toHaveBeenCalled();`  -- namespace the actions object, but this gives a different error ` [vuex] actions should be function or object with "handler" function but "actions.setting" is {}.`

Comment: Updated my answer.  Wrap with modules: {...} when creating the vuex store

Comment: that makes perfect sense...(hopefully) final question: how do I reference the function in my test? when I do `expect(books.actions.setBooks).toHaveBeenCalled()` I get `books is not defined`; when I try `expect(actions.setBooks).toHaveBeenCalled()` I get ` [vuex] module namespace not found in mapActions(): books/`

Comment: I figured it out: just needed to add `namespaced: true` to `books` module. thanks for your help!